# C++ Cli code stucked

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I took out the unnecessary parts of the code to clarify what the code is supposed to represent and what code should actually work because I see that confuses you extra space in the text in quotation marks.

```
MySqlDataReader^ myReader;
try
{
  conDataBase -> Open();
  myReader = cmdDataBase -> ExecuteReader();
  //   int count = 0;
  while (myReader -> Read())
  {

    count = count + 1; // This piece of code I want to rewrite,from here to the bottom
                       // of the page,password should not be in the numbers but in the
                       // letters, and that's what I do not know how to do it. 
                       // Statement if should be if (char*) or something like that.
  }  

  if (count == 1)
  {
    MessageBox::Show ("Username and password are correct");
  }
  else if (count > 1)
  {
    MessageBox::Show ("Username and password are duplicates ... access denied!");
  }
  else
  {
    MessageBox::Show ("Username and password are incorrect ... Please enter your username and password!");
  }
}
catch ( Exception^ ex)
{
  MessageBox::Show(ex -> Message);
}
}
}
};
```

Comment: Bobby Tables was here.

Comment: What a mess, in every single aspect. From lack of comments, to wrong usage patterns (readers?), `select *`, clear text passwords (thanks for showing us I guess), never disposing OS handles (find your `finally` handlers...), useless objects, direct text box SQL injection, kindergartner level of aesthetics... Truly pathetic. And stop clogging the network with your `select *`->`while valid ++cnt` pattern, look up `select count(*)`.

Comment: First of all, along with all of the stuff that @Blindy said, don't do this `String^` in C++, that is CLI syntax

Comment: The question does not make any sense. How to make a password? What does that mean?

Comment: Ok, brains, instead of blabbing around, help if U can. Or if u know.

Comment: @Kanjah77 I've added the tag C++-CLI. This is what you are using, not standard C++. In the future, make sure you use this tag when asking questions, as the syntax and solution can be very different.

Comment: Ok,sorry about that I've tagged visual studio and VC++ but only thing that was standing at the end is C...

Comment: This code works with numbers as password but i need to make password with letters and chars...

Comment: @Kanjah77 Looks like your code here has extra spaces, so the SQL statement would be `... and Password = ' password ';`.

Comment: @crashmstr do u have pm or something?

Comment: he meant, try changing `... Password = ' " + this -> password_txt -> Text + " ';"` to `... Password = '" + this -> password_txt -> Text + "';"`. Note that I removed two spaces: one after Password=', and other just before the '; at the end. Having those spaces there can damage the string-comparison and coercion on the database side. Regardless of that, even if you get it working, read about query-parameters and try to use them instead. It will be safer and noone will be able to delete your tables by writing their usernames as `';DROP TABLE eid;select '`. Currently they can do that.

Comment: Extra spaces are no problem at all. I've created database and i've imported it into the code. I've created one property named password and set value to int. How can i, when i maked changes with that property "password" as characters in database, how can i create a loop in code which would be password with text and characters....????

Comment: Is this the best you can, instead of helping to put this question off-topic?? Only because you do not know answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided **does not work** on **any numbers**.

The only thing it does is

- construct some SQL query
- check its result

During the SQL-query-construction, the code does not assume any "numbers" to be provided. It actually uses a variable called `password_txt->Text`, which suggests it's some form of `TextBox` control. The code gets the "Text" from it and pastes it into the query with no assumptions. If the "Text" contained numbers, it would paste numbers. If the "Text" contained "mom_dad-and-MYDOG", the code would paste exactly that. Also, the code already ensures that the text will be wrapped with quotes (`...' " + Text + " ' ...`), so the SQL syntax will be valid both for numbers and text.

BTW. mind that pasting the text into the query, with quotes ensured or not, forms a serious security issues. What if the text contains a quote? you really should be using QueryParameters here. This is serious, but this is a whole lot different story. Be sure to read about it.

Getting back to numbers/text - So, **this code** does not care about "numbers". If your application does not allow the password to be "text", then the cause must sit in some other chunk of the code.

Judging from that `password_txt -> Text`, you've probably got a TextBox or something similar there. Check its `events` section. It is very probable that you will find some TextChanged or KeyPressed or KeyDown event handler that will, for example, filter-out all key presses except numbers.

// edit: also check out the thing suggested by **crashmstr** - remove that extra spaces near the quotes I just mentioned. `' 213 '` might be coercible to 213, but `' mom '` will not match "mom" in the table. Another thing - be sure to check what datatype the `password` column is in the database itself ;)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the set question.

Comment: Sorry, but this is going nowhere. You are either unable to fully express what you want to change/achieve, or you are unable to notice your true source of problem. I think you are too focused on the symptoms and general things. You need to first understand what exactly happens in the code and know what effects which part of the code is responsible for. Take a few hours break, rest, clear your mind, then read the code carefully and play with it. Try replacing values like `pass_txt->Text` with constant values like L"fooo" and check what queries fly to the database. It should show you what's wrong

Comment: And if it does not - at least you will be now sure that this code is not the one you should be looking at. Anyways, you need to ensure 3 things: database columns must be able to store text (not only numbers), your GUI elements must be able to provide text (not only numbers), and your SQL-query-generator must correctly add the text to the query template. If you get that, you should be able to use textual passwords. Assuming of course that you really want that. Sadly, with the things you write, now I'm not even sure about that.

Comment: Probably I did not express very well, I modified the text in the code so it will be easier to understand now.

Comment: This is solved, how can i mark this theme as solved?

Comment: Pick any answer and click on the big "V" mark on the left of the text.  It should be visible right under the "score" thing. Clicking on the "V" will "accept this answer" and give score some points to the person who wrote it. At the moment, there's only my answer, so there's little to choose from. If you don't like it, you can can write your own answer and explain what was wrong and how you solved that. Then, you could click on the "V" at your answer and you will "accept your own answer" (so ~ you solved it all by yourself, etc). That's 100% ok to do so.

Comment: However, the question is currently "on hold" (locked), so you will probably be not able to write an answer. You also may not be able to accept" anything. I actually simply dont know how it works. Your question was "locked" because people thought it is too unclear and probably will not be answerable in any decent way, unless you add more information or explain a few things in a more understandable way. There are ways to get your question "unlocked" (re-opened) -  you can edit it, add/explain more things, people will see it and after some time they may unlock it back.

Comment: Really, that's great you managed to solve the problem. Good job!:) but personally, I think this question will not help others much in solving their problems. I think (still personally) that it'd be easier if you simply delete the question (there's a 'delete' button under your text). It got significant negative score (a -8 is quite much), so convincing others to reopen it may be hard or time-consuming. Of course, you don't need to delete it if you don't want.  I'm just trying to tell you what options you've got.

Comment: Thank you very much,only You were very helpful. Those people who are locked this question they had no intention of helping in any way, They are as real ignorant, threw the negative points and close the topic because they did not know how to respond to anything. You're the only one willing to answer me some, that's completely accurate but, as we concluded, as I have not expressed well in a given topic, it was not helpful even though, everything you wrote is completely true. 
Thank you very much, anyway!